# Versionize HTTP methods web api2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Which is the best way to versionize http methods web api2? Each version of web api called from different version of upgrated application.

Comment: There is no best way to versioning endpoints. You can use version number in the url, you can use accept http header for that, you can use numbers or dates etc. This question is opinion-based. Choose the versioning method you want and ask specific question if you will have problems implementing it

Comment: This is definitely opinion-based, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer. IMO you need to consider that what you are versioning is the contract, not the API itself. The consumer can say, "I want the response as JSON", therefore they should also be able to say, "I want the response as JSON in the v1 form." As a result, we chose to use the Accept header. Here's more info, https://www.troyhunt.com/your-api-versioning-is-wrong-which-is/

Answer (score 1):

Versioning an API can be complex. The way that I typically do it is to setup versioned routes and controllers.

This makes my routes look like this

```
https://api.example.com/api/v1/
https://api.example.com/api/v2/
https://api.example.com/api/v3/
```

Then I include a "baseUrl" and "version" in the client. So it knows how to assemble that into a complete Uri. This means my project structure looks something like

```
|- Controllers
|-----\VersionController.cs
|-----\v1
|----------\HomeController.cs
|----------\AuthController.cs
|-----\v2
|----------\HomeController.cs
|----------\AuthController.cs
```

Additionally, I provide an endpoint that never changes form and only provides the available API versions.

```
https://api.example.com/api/version
```

And this returns a value that looks something like:

```
{
    "currentVersion": 3,
    "minVersion": 1
}
```

This way, clients can know when their API version is deprecated and no longer available. Instead of just throwing a 404.